# How to read an input file char by char using a Scanner?

Tags: java, input, io

I have to use `Scanner`, so is there a `nextChar()` instead of `nextLine()` method that I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert in an array of chars.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ScanXan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile.txt")));
            while (s.hasNext())
            {
               String str = s.next(); 
                char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();
                // do something
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you *have* to use a `Scanner` (as you noted in your edit), try this:

```
myScanner.useDelimiter("(?<=.)");
```

Now `myScanner` should read character by character.

---

You might want to use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) instead (if you can) - it has a [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) method that reads a single character. For instance, this will read and print the first character of your file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
System.out.println((char)br.read());
br.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the line into characters using `String.toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're committed to using `Scanner` then you can use `next(String pattern)`.

```
String character = scanner.next(".");
```

The above returns a `String` of length 1 -- that is, you get a character, but as a string.