# scanner next() only -n characters from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there a way to read next -n characters in java scanner?
Let's say I want to read 16 characters. I read a line, take 16 characters out of it, hop in new line and then continue with reading the SAME line. If it is needed, read a new line and take the other characters from it.

Comment: is it your answer or your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple example of reading a file char by char , and appending a new line after 16 characters

**Excerpt from** [How to read an input file char by char using a Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370053/how-to-read-an-input-file-char-by-char-using-a-scanner)

```
public class FileReader
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scanner = null;
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
      scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("d:\\text.txt")));
      while (scanner.hasNext())
      {
        String str = scanner.next();
        char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();
        for (char c : myChar)
        {
          stringBuilder.append(c);
          count++;
          if (count == 16)
          {
            count = 0;
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
      if (scanner != null)
      {
        scanner.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```